# Кэширование pdf файлов браузером

Tags: .htaccess, apache, кэширование

Возможно ли на стороне сервера запретить кэшировать браузеру `pdf` файл, открываемый по ссылке. Сервер `apache`.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы на стороне сервера не настроили кэширование pdf файлов, то он кэшироваться и не будет. На сервере настраивается срок и типы файлов, которые необходимо кэшировать браузеру.